# Position div under absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-position, absolute

I'm using React. I have a div, that is positioned absolute, I'm trying to show another div, under that div, but is not working. The only way is to make the div relative instead of absolute, but is cutting off the text of the slider, so it has to stay absolute. If I put the div inside the first div's component, it shows behind it, but I need it to go under. Here's the code

You can see the code of the first div here in codepen: [first div code](https://codepen.io/PriscilaCunha/pen/XbqOWL)

Now, here is the code of the main component:

```
function Home() {
    
    return (
      <Styled.Container>
        <Row>
          <Styled.CarouselContainer>
            <TextCarousel/>
          </Styled.CarouselContainer>
        </Row>
        </Styled.Container>
    );
}

export default Home
```

I've tried 2 things: one is getting the new div, on the main component like this:

```
function Home() {
    
    return (
      <Styled.Container>
        <Row>
          <Styled.CarouselContainer>
            <TextCarousel/>
          </Styled.CarouselContainer>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <SystemInfo/>  //THIS IS THE NEW DIV
        </Row>
        </Styled.Container>
    );
}

export default Home
```

and the other one is putting the new div inside the componente of the first div, like this:

```
function TextCarousel() {
   
  return (
    <Styled.Container>
      <div id="textSlider" className="row">
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4 iamCol">
        <img alt="iotek logo" src='/assets/images/logo.png'/>
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-8 slideCol">
        <div className="scroller">
          <div className="inner">
              {HomeCarouselText.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <p>{item.text}</p>
                )
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Styled.MoveSlider >
              <i id="arrow-down-slider" className="fa fa-chevron-down arrow-down-slider" aria-hidden="true"/>
      </Styled.MoveSlider>

      <SystemInfo/> //THIS IS THE NEW DIV
    </Styled.Container>
    )
}

export default TextCarousel
```

To explain better, here's how the site is looking right now
[image]

I managed to move the hello down, by giving the new div a bottom: 0 and position: absolute.

The site has to be responsive, so I can't be working with absolute positioning on every div, so what can I make so that the new div, and all the future ones, stay under the absolute positioned div?

Comment: I think there is no need to use an absolute position here. Did you try using `display: flex` property?

Comment: The code of the slider is not mine, so I'm gonna try and change it to flexbox to see what happens